# Maintaining a mongodb with tweets that match a given tag

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, twython

I have to keep an mongodb with tweets that match a given tag. Also, I have to keep it updated with the latest data of the tweet. And I need to create indexes as 'id_str'. 
An exception occurs when I run this code and do not know why. Just I know that there is a problem in the 'for'.

```
def getSearchTagTwitter(tag):

  db = connexMongoDB()
  t = loginTwython2()
  search = t.search(q=tag, count=100)
  data = search['statuses']
  try:
      for tweet in data:
          db.twittersearch.ensureIndex(tweet['id_str'])
          db.twittersearch.update(tweet)
  except Exception:
      print "Error tag"
      time.sleep(60*15)
      getSearchTagTwitter(tag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is raised by `ensureIndex` as the syntax doesn't look quite right. The correct syntax is:

```
db.twittersearch.ensureIndex('id_str')
```

There is also no need to create the index in each iteration of the for loop, you can just declare it once and it will get automatically updated. Please note that `ensureIndex` is now deprecated, you should use `create_index` instead.

In addition your `update` statement does not look correct either and should be as follow:

```
 db.twittersearch.update_one({"id_str":"12344"}, tweet, upsert=True)
```

Comment: It seems that this is the solution, but still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I want to avoid duplicates. Can I do that with "save" ?

Comment: "Save" is deprecated http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=save#pymongo.collection.Collection.save